# GeoPandas and Cartopy how to dynamically zoom to Multiline

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, cartopy

I am new to GeoPandas and Cartopy.

I am trying to generate map plots for different regions dynamically.
When generating the image from geopandas ('df.plot()') the size is correct, but when I generate a plot using Cartopy the Multiline appears very small and I cannot find a way to fit it to the figure. What I am doing wrong?

```
import psycopg2 as db
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

con = db.connect(connection_string)
sql = 'select geom from table'
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con,crs= 21781) 
df.plot(color='black')

crs_epsg = ccrs.epsg('21781')
df_epsg = df.to_crs(epsg='21781')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'projection': crs_epsg},figsize = (5,2.5))
axs.add_geometries(df_epsg['geom'], crs=crs_epsg,facecolor="none", edgecolor='black')
extend = [650000,690000,22000,260000]
axs.set_extent(extend,crs=crs_epsg)
axs.outline_patch.set_visible(False)
axs.background_patch.set_visible(False)
axs.background_patch.set_alpha(0)
fig.patch.set_alpha(0)

plt.show()
```

Here the image of GeoPandas directly:
[image: GeoPandas image]

And this is the image made with GeoPandas and Cartopy:
[image]

Here one of the Multistrings: [Sample MultiString](https://pastebin.com/aDeYSJDz)

Comment: What are you using `cartopy` for? In the code above it has not real role.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to plot these maps with it. I have now plotted them using geopandas and that worked well. I removed it from my code.